# Update foreign key field in table to primary key values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

After adding `SID` to the `TRANSACTIONS` table, I need to update `SID` column in `TRANSACTIONS` based off `STORE_NBR` in the `STORES` table.

Basically, I want to update the correct `SID` in transactions to the `SID` in `STORES` based on common column `STORE_NBR` in both tables.

Comment: change TRANSACTIONS.SID to STORES.SID in your subquery. In your case, you try to update TRANSACTIONS.SID to TRANSACTIONS.SID (that is NULL at the moment)

Comment: Thanks. Done. But the query still doesn't work.

Comment: have added code and dbfiddle below

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (pay attention to using aliases for different tables with the same name column in one query):

```
update transactions
set transactions.sid = stores.sid
from stores
where stores.store_nbr = transactions.store_nbr;
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=bca18a732b5856a652d41ab2fa27aca7)

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` stores and transactions to set your new column:

```
UPDATE transactions SET sid = s.sid 
FROM 
transactions t JOIN stores s ON t.store_nbr = s.store_nbr;
```

If you assume there could occur transactions without corresponding store and you don't want to leave those entries `NULL`, you can use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to force a certain value for them, as example 0:

```
UPDATE transactions SET sid = COALESCE(s.sid,0)
FROM 
transactions t LEFT JOIN stores s ON t.store_nbr = s.store_nbr;
```